# Переменные какого типа можно подставлять в strcmp?

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели

Имею два массива данных, которые мне в процессе нужно сравнивать:

```
const static uint8_t main_password[12] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
static uint8_t password[12];
```

При попытке сравнения этих двух массивов при помощи функции strcmp

```
if (!strcmp(password, main_password))
```

компилятор IDE IAR выдает предупреждение:

> Warning[Pe167]: argument of type "unsigned char *" is incompatible
>   with parameter of type "char const *"

При следующей записи

```
if (!strcmp((char const*)password, main_password))
```

> Warning[Pe167]: argument of type "unsigned char const *" is
>   incompatible with parameter of type "char const *"

При беглой проверке программа работает. 
Вопрос: что не нравится компилятору и не будет ли программа глючить в будущем?

Comment: gcc вообще не ругается, а для g++ достаточно оба аргумента привести к `(char *)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь имеется интересная особенность. Строковые функции принимают аргументы, которые неявно преобразуются в указатели типа `char *` или `const char *`. Если после преобразования аргумент имеет тип `char *`, то он еще преобразуется в функции к типу `const char *`в случае если соответствующий параметр имеет квалификатор `const`.

Внутри же самих функций при обработке строк он преобразуется к типу `unsigned char *` или `const unsigned char *` в зависимости от того, как объявлен соответствующий параметр: либо с квалификатором const либо без него.

Из стандарта C (7.23.1 String function conventions):

> 3 For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be
>   interpreted as if it had the type **unsigned char** (and therefore every
>   possible object representation is valid and has a different value).

То есть приведение типов в вашем вызове, фактически, избыточное, и делается лишь для того, чтобы можно было вызвать функции в соответствии с объявлением ее формальных параметров.

В вашем случае следовало написать

```
if (!strcmp( ( char * )password, ( const char * )main_password))
```

или

```
if (!strcmp( ( const char * )password, ( const char * )main_password))
```

Имейте в виду, что функция `strcmp` служит для сравнения строк. Если же вы хотите сравнить символьные массивы, то вам следует использовать `memcmp` или если один из массивов будет содержать строку, а другой нет, то `strncmp`. Для `memcmp` никакого приведения типов для аргументов указывать не надо, так как параметры имеют тип `const void *`